# how can i add class to errorsummay without remove header message

Tags: css, forms, yii

I'm trying to add a css class to the errorSummary() in yii framwork but after add class i have not header error default
how can i add class to errorsummay without remove header message

```
<?php echo  $form->errorSummary($model, '', '', array('class' => 'alert alert-error')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very simple one,

you can pass the class you need this way,

```
<?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model, null, null, array('class'=>'className')); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo  $form->errorSummary($model, null, null, array('class'=>'className')); ?>
```

so this will allow you add the class while you have the header.

check here for more information : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#errorSummary-detail

since you are passing, empty string for header it causes the header issue. default value is null for `$header`.

```
public string errorSummary(mixed $models, string $header=NULL, string $footer=NULL, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set attribute [errorMessageCssClass](http://yiiapi.com/CActiveForm#errorMessageCssClass-detail) of class `CActiveForm` want:

and also [errorSummary()](http://yiiapi.com/CActiveForm#errorSummary-detail) has `htmlOptions` !

```
  public string errorSummary(mixed $models, string $header=NULL, string $footer=NULL, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Adjust code like this.

```
echo $form->errorSummary($model,NULL,NULL,array('class'=>'alert alert-error'));
```