# How to show form errorSummary() in red?

Tags: php, html, forms, yii, widget

I have this form:

```
<?php 
   $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'login-form',
            'enableClientValidation' => true,
            'clientOptions' => array(
                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            ),
        ));


    $errorMsg = $form->errorSummary($userModel, "", "");

    if(!empty($errorMsg))
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align:center; width:800px; margin:auto;">' . $errorMsg . '</div>';
         echo '<br>';
     }

    $form->labelEx($userModel, 'email');
    echo $form->textField($userModel, 'email');
    $form->error($userModel, 'email');
?>
```

I am trying to print the error message when the email is invalid, but I want to print it using the red background from bootstrap. The problem is that without any errors it still shows the red bar.

It seems that this happens because `errorSummary()` is never really `null`

---

output:
[image]

Comment: you mean **$errorMsg** instead of errorSummery() or? post a var_dump($errorMsg)

Comment: `$errorMsg = errorSummary()` . But the var dump prints `NULL`.

Comment: Use *isset($errorMsg)* in the if condition. You can find the answer here *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615747/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-empty*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats not how things work with the summary.

The `errorSummary()`-function always returns content to be added to the page.
The function makes sure the returned `div` is marked as hidden if there are no errors.

The reason it is done like that is so that the summary is there for front-end validation as well. The javascript will update and hide/show the `div` when needed.

So basically you should do this:

```
echo $form->errorSummary($userModel, "", "", array('class' => "alert alert-danger"));
```

And get rid of the extra `if(!empty($errorMsg)) ...`

Comment: Yup, that works. I just found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718652/how-can-i-add-class-to-errorsummay-without-remove-header-message

Answer (score 0):

You can change class like this:

```
<?= $form->errorSummary($model, ['class' => 'alert alert-danger']); ?>
```